# NSDate Formatting individually

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsformatter

I'm using NSDateFormatter to format NSDate variables like this:

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd/MM";
```

I want to provide an unique format only for the first day of year(setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy").

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first day of year is allways 01.01 or in your case 01/01 and then you can add the year or what do you mean?

Comment: You have to extract the day from the `NSDate` using `NSDateComponents` and then conditionally use a different format.  Not too difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this to format your date,

```
NSDate *dateInAction = [NSDate date]; //Your date here
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth fromDate:dateInAction];
NSInteger day = [components day];
NSInteger month = [components month];
if (day==1 && month==1) {
    // Set formatter for first day of year
}else{
    // all other days
}
```